# Russian characters on svg text tag not showing correctly

Tags: html, svg, character, font-face

I have on the site Svg and there will be **Russian** texts
but the text is displayed incorrectly when I open the browser.

this is my code

```
<g>
  <rect id="XMLID_2_" x="409.1" y="102.3" transform="matrix(0.7071 -0.7071 0.7071 0.7071 25.8097 371.5413)" class="cubes hex-init" data-title="backend" data-content="backend-desc" data-color="#333333" width="104.6" height="104.6"/>
  <image style="overflow:visible;" width="256" height="256" id="XMLID_18_" xlink:href="assets/img/time.png"  transform="matrix(0.1826 0 0 0.1826 440 110.7045)"></image>
  <text id="XMLID_22_" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 425.0002 174.6665)" class="st1 st2">Собственный график</text>
</g>
```

1. And the rusult is

> ```
> РЎРѕР±СЃС‚РІРµРЅРЅС‹Р№ РіСЂР°С„РёРє
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add meta charset in your html head

```
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
```